# fa-IR.resx at Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, globalization

Why fa-IR.resx is unknown at the Visual studio 2010

Comment: fa-IR.resx is a resource file (probably containing Iranian translations of some texts). A file is never *unknown* to VS2010 unless it's referenced improperly. So please try and be bit more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: There is something odd going on, there are two entries for Persian, it no longer mentions "Iran".  The question is hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use fa-IR.resx. You should use fa.resx.
for default resource with file name 'default.resx' use 'default.fa.resx'